# Error during parse the genesis file of the cosmos blockchain

Tags: configuration, blockchain, cosmos

I am setting up bdjuno for cosmos, and during parse the genesis file I get follow err.

```
$ bdjuno parse genesis-file
ERROR: failed to unmarshal genesis state: unexpected end of JSON input
```

What is the matter?

I have tried to review the genesis file and its format is ok.

Comment: Can you show us the genesis file?

Comment: there was a problem in genesis-file. And I have fixed that already, thanks